# biblatex, biber, is it possible to \printbibliography between two years?

Tags: biblatex, biber

With `biblatex` and Biber, is it possible to print all the bibliography (`\printbibliography`) from (let's say) 2003 to 2008 in one section? And then in another section print all the bibliography from 2009 to 2016?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with Biber's ability to dynamically rewrite bibliographical information using regular expressions.  This example prints only the entries in the range 2003--2008 and 2009--2015 even though the document cites all entries, which range from 2001 to 2016.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{a,
  date =     2001,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{b,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{c,
  date =     2005,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{d,
  date =     2007,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{e,
  date =     2009,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{f,
  date =     2011,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{g,
  date =     2013,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{h,
  date =     2015,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{i,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=date,  match=\regexp{200([3-8])}, %
            fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={ONE}, append, ]
      \step[fieldsource=date,  match=\regexp{(2009|201[0-5])}, %
            fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={TWO}, append, ]
}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword=ONE, title={Group One (2003--2008)}]

\printbibliography[keyword=TWO, title={Group Two (2009--2015)}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to define two `check`s with the conditions for the years

```
\defbibcheck{old}{
  \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2003}
    {\skipentry}
    {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2008}
      {\skipentry}
      {}
    }
}

\defbibcheck{new}{
  \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2009}
    {\skipentry}
    {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2016}
      {\skipentry}
      {}
    }
}
```

and then use the `check` option of \printbibliography`, namelly:

```
\printbibliography[check=old, title={2003--2008}]

\printbibliography[check=new, title={2009-2016}]
```

Comment: Ohhh, you beat me by fourty seconds or so.

Comment: @moewe not putting `\iffieldint{year}` saved me the 40 seconds :-)

Comment: Oh, this is good too. Never noticed the `\defbibcheck` command before.... (+1 for both)

Answer (score 5):

jon's answer with Biber's regex is brilliant, but you can also use bibchecks from within the document. We just need to compare years with `etoolbox`'s facilities.
Unfortunately we have only `<` and `>`, so our checks will look like this

```
\defbibcheck{yrs0308}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2002}} and test {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2009}}}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}

\defbibcheck{yrs1015}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2009}} and test {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2016}}}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}
```

Full MWE (adapted from jon's)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{a,
  date =     2001,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{b,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{c,
  date =     2005,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{d,
  date =     2007,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{e,
  date =     2009,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{f,
  date =     2011,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{g,
  date =     2013,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{h,
  date =     2015,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{i,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibcheck{yrs0308}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2002}} and test {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2009}}}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}

\defbibcheck{yrs1015}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2009}} and test {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2016}}}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[check=yrs0308, title={Group One (2003--2008)}]
\printbibliography[check=yrs1015, title={Group Two (2009--2015)}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. However, I had to change the code a little bit to make it work. Probably because I had another \map (???) ... I don't understand everything and the doc of biblatex is quite heavy!

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map[overwrite=true]{
        \step[fieldsource=author, match=myself, final]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=own, append]
}
     \map[overwrite=true]{
        \step[fieldsource=year,  match=\regexp{200([3-8])},final]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=ONE, append]
}
     \map[overwrite=true]{
        \step[fieldsource=year,  match=\regexp{(2009|201[0-5])},final]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={TWO}, append]
}}}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,type=article,heading=none,resetnumbers=true,keyword=ONE]
```

Could you please, @jon, clarify what does "final" stand for? Why was the line

```
\step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
```

necessary in my case?

Comment: It is hard to say why these things are necessary in your case because you have not provided *any* information about your actual `.tex` file; however, I'm not convinced things are as necessary as it may seem right now. Please provide an MWE. (If you were already using a sourcemap, why didn't you mention this?)

Comment: Regarding the `final`: the point is that this term terminates the processing of the parent map. It must be used with discretion.

Comment: @jon What is crucial here is that the code also appends a comma to the field. When you append `ONE` to a non-empty keyword list, `primary,own` for example, you get `primary,ownONE` which doesn't work for obvious reasons. If the field is empty, however, this adds a comma, so that in the end we have `,ONE`, which I think gives a warning about an empty keyword, but causes no further trouble.

Comment: @moewe -- Yes, indeed. I figured that might be an issue, but I was trying to promote the idea that this is yet another case where an MWE is actually useful/important. I think (without having tried) that it might simply be easier to `append` a `,ONE` all in one step ... which is why I said it may not be 'necessary' to add that `\step` in my earlier comment.  (And, depending on what is going on, I was going to suggest that `append` may or may not be the right choice.)

Comment: @jon Yes, adding `,ONE` should do the same. With a bit of regex foo one might be able to append the comma only when necessary, but I haven't yet found an elegant way of doing that. I see your point about MWEs here, sometimes it is hard to know how far to reduce all the code involved.