# biblatex, biber, how to \printbibliography year after year from xxxx to yyyy?

Tags: biblatex, biber, loops

With biblatex and Biber, how to create a loop on the years to print bibliography year after year in the following manner:

```
\section{2016}
    \subsection{Article}
        \printbibliography of all articles published in 2017
    \subsection{inproceedings}
        \printbibliography of all papers in proceedings published in 2017
    \subsection{in Misc}
        \printbibliography of all misc published in 2017

\section{2015}
    etc. for all bib entries and all years.
```

Here is an example of the desired result: https://malti.fr/index.php/publication-list-per-year.

Some further enhancements could be:

- The starting year automatically set up to the older entry year of the bib file,
- The end year automatically set up to the most recent entry year of the bib file,
- In case there is no paper published corresponding to a given (sub-)section, then that (sub-)section does not appear, (i.e.) no (sub-)section appears empty.

Printing bibliography between two years was resolved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346270/biblatex-biber-is-it-possible-to-printbibliography-between-two-years). Thanks.

EDITED. Here is a MWE borrowed and modified from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346270/biblatex-biber-is-it-possible-to-printbibliography-between-two-years) to answer @samcarter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{a,
  date =     2001,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{b,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{c,
  date =     2004,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}
  
@Article{d,
  date =     2007,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{e,
  date =     2009,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{f,
  date =     2011,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{g,
  date =     2013,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{h,
  date =     2015,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{i,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@patent{l,
  year =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Patent 1},
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@inproceedings{j,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title 1},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@patent{o,
  year =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Patent 1},
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

 @patent{m,
  year =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Patent 2},
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{n,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

    
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map[overwrite=true]{
            \step[fieldsource=author,match=Amy,final]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=own, append]
}}}


\defbibcheck{2016}{%There must be a better way to code "different from" 2016
  \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2016}
    {\skipentry}
    {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2016}
      {\skipentry}
      {}
    }
}

\defbibcheck{2015}{%There must be a better way to code "different from" 2015
  \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2015}
    {\skipentry}
    {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2015}
      {\skipentry}
      {}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section*{2016}
    \printbibliography[check=2016, keyword=own, resetnumbers=true, type=article, heading=subbibliography, title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[check=2016, keyword=own, resetnumbers=true, type=inproceedings, heading=subbibliography, title={Inproceedings}]
    \printbibliography[check=2016, keyword=own, resetnumbers=true, type=patent, heading=subbibliography, title={Patent}]
\section*{2015}
    \printbibliography[check=2015, keyword=own, resetnumbers=true, type=article, heading=subbibliography, title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[check=2015, keyword=own, resetnumbers=true, type=inproceedings, heading=subbibliography, title={Inproceedings}]
    \printbibliography[check=2015, keyword=own, resetnumbers=true, type=patent, heading=subbibliography, title={Patent}]

\end{document}
```

However, I've got an undesired output with headings `Inproceedings` and `Patent` printed with an empty content in year 2015. I'd like not to have any heading if the content is empty.

Back to my request. How to create a loop from 2016 down to 2001 printing the bibliography year after year according to the types (Article, Inproceedings, Patent, Misc, ...)?

Another enhancement would be:

- to create an inner loop which loops around the different types (Article, Inproceedings, Patent, Misc, ...) for each year.

EDITED

Find below a MWE, with the proposed solutions, which however points out the compilation pb when using htlatex/biber/htlatex. See the comment below posted on Feb, 22nd, 2020.

RE-EDITED on March, 12th, 2020: a misc ref is added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{b,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

  @misc{ccc,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {misc, LLL},
  title =    {MISC},
  journaltitle = {Journal-misc},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{c,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, BBB},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{d,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{i,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@patent{l,
  year =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Patent 1},
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@inproceedings{j,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title 1},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@patent{o,
  year =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Patent 1},
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

 @patent{m,
  year =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Patent 2},
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

@Article{n,
  date =     2016,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141}}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=article]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=inproceedings]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{patent}
      \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=patent]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{rasha}{
  \sort[direction=ascending]{
    \field{year}}
  \sort{\field{presort}}
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {}
  
\newcounter{myyear}
\setcounter{myyear}{0}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{\value{myyear}}
  {\section*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\printfield{year}}
   \setcounter{myyear}{\thefield{year}}%
   \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
   \xdef\mylastentrytype{}%
   }%
  {}%
  \iffieldequals{entrytype}{\mylastentrytype}
    {}
    { \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}
        {\subsection*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Journal Articles}}
        { \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inproceedings}
            {\subsection*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Conference Papers}
             \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
            }
            {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}
                {\subsection*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Patents}
                 \setcounter{enumi}{0}  
                }
                {}
            }
        }
      \xdef\mylastentrytype{\thefield{entrytype}}
    }
  \item
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
    \begin{refcontext}[sorting=rasha]
        \printbibliography[title={Publication list by year}]
    \end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounds all doable with biblatex. Have a look at the filter options of biblatex. It should be fairly easy to just print the entries of a specific year. Can you please give us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to have something to start with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution (proof of concept) that cycles inside a single `\printbibliography`.

The solution depends on a specifically created sorting schema (here, we use the fact that `article` lexicographically  precedes `inproceedings` which in turns proceeds `patent`). A more robust would define a specified sorting schema (and eventually a Source Map) for an appropriate ordering over the entry types.

Also, for simplicity, the solution assumes  that only `article`, `inproceedings` and `patents` entries are presented in the bibliography file (easy to extend with a "Other publications" category).

The first step is to define the sorting order:

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{rasha}{
  \sort[direction=ascending]{
    \field{year}
    \field{entrytype}
  }
}
```

Then, we redefine the `bibliography` environment.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {}
```

The trick here is to remove `\item` from the last element (the iteration over the bib item). This is delegated to the single entries.

The final step is to redefine the `begentry` macro (which is executed at the begin on standard bibliography drivers.

```
\def\mylastentrytype{}

\newcounter{myyear}
\setcounter{myyear}{0}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{\value{myyear}}
  {\section*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\printfield{year}}
   \setcounter{myyear}{\thefield{year}}%
   \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
   \xdef\mylastentrytype{}%
   }%
  {}%
  \iffieldequals{entrytype}{\mylastentrytype}
    {}
    { \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}
        {\subsection*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Journal Articles}}
        { \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inproceedings}
            {\subsection*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Conference Papers}
             \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
            }
            {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}
                {\subsection*{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Patents}
                 \setcounter{enumi}{0}  
                }
                {}
            }
        }
      \xdef\mylastentrytype{\thefield{entrytype}}
    }
  \item
}
```

Given that the sorting schema use `year` as first parameter, the initial condition checks whether we  have an increment in the year, if so it emits a `\section` command, and the set the counter for  the year to the year of the last entry processed.

The second parameter of the sorting schema is the `entrytype` of the entry. Thus we have to check if  the current entry is of the same type of the previous one (stored in `\mylastentrytype`). If this is not the case, we check if the entry type is one of `article`, `inproceedings` or `patent`. If it is then, we print the corresponding section (reseting the counter for the enumeration)

Finally, we have to instruct to use the sorting schema.

```
\nocite{*}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=rasha]
\printbibliography[title={Publication list by year}]
\end{refcontext}
```

With the bibliography given in the MWE this produce the following output (in a two column format)

[image]

EDIT Apparently `\sort{\field{entrytype}}` is not recognised during the sorting phase. Thus an alternative is to declare a source map to populate the `presort` field using the `\pertype` specification, namely:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=article]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=inproceedings]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{patent}
      \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=patent]
    }
  }
}
```

and change the sorting template  (notice the `\DeclareSortingSchema` is now deprecated) to

```
\DeclareSortingTemplate{rasha}{
  \sort[direction=ascending]{
    \field{year}}
  \sort{\field{presort}}
}
```

The output, with the extended MWE, is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Guido. Your solution works fine when the bib file contains an ordered bibliography. However, if the bibliography is not ordered, there is a problem because let's say in 2016, we'll find "Journal articles", "conference papers", then "Journal articles" again ... Could you please elaborate a work around regarding this problem.

Comment: I've modified the MWE to show the problem that appears in 2016 when the bibliography is not ordered.

Comment: @rasha I guess the only change needed is `\DeclareSortingScheme{rasha}{
  \sort[direction=ascending]{
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{entrytype}
  }
}` (modulo line breaks)

Comment: @moewe Apparently `\sort{\field{entrytype}}` has no effect on sorting. According to the documentation it should, but it does not. Is this a bug in `biber/biblatex`?

Comment: I reported this to PLK https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/206

Comment: @moewe I saw the latest comments in github.com/plk/biber/issues/206    could you please tell me, when you talk about v.2.10, you mean the version of what package? Could you send me the fix you downloaded from sourceforge or inform me in how much time is it usually available in CTAN? Thanks.

Comment: @rasha I was talking about Biber 2.10. It will hopefully be on CTAN and MikTeX/TeX live by the end of the week, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: @moewe, 2 years later, I came across another problem. Everything works fine when compiling with the sequence latex/biber/latex. However, I need to generate an html based on the mentioned code, and when I try to compile with the sequence: htlatex/biber/htlatex, I get some ugly messages at the second htlatex compilation of the kind: ``(./MWE.bbl)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \c:\end:itm
l.147 ...ography[title={Publication list by year}]
?'' The obtained html file misses numbers and there is no newline at each new entry.

Comment: You can use the last EDITED MWE example with the suggested solutions.

Comment: @rasha If it works with LaTeX (and it does, I just checked) but not with `htlatex` then this is most likely a `htlatex` incompatibility or bug. I can't help you there and suggest you ask about the issue at the mailing list https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex4ht or report it directly at https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?group=tex4ht

Comment: @moewe, I'm facing a new problem and spent yesterday all day long trying to figure it out without success. I've updated my MWE (check above), by adding 1 reference of misc-type. I'd like this reference to be ignored because it is not of (Article, Inproceeding, or Patent type). Instead of ignoring it, the macro prints it at the end of the last type of references by reseting the numbering. This pb was first pointed out as a comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529782/htlatex-biber-htlatex-compilation-error-not-present-in-latex-biber-latex?noredirect=1#comment1345795_529782

Comment: @rasha you can define a filter or a check to exclude references that are not of the appropriate type. `\defbibfilter{include}{type=journal or type=patent or type=inproceedings}` or `\defbibcheck{exclude}{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\skipentry}`}

Comment: @Guido, I'm having an issue with the solution you proposed 3 years ago, as I cannot simultaneously choose an authors name and do the pre-sorting. What I tried at each of the 3 map(s) is:     
     \map{
           \pertype{inproceedings}
           \step[fieldsource=author,match={Malti}]
           \step[fieldset=presort,fieldvalue=inproceedings]
     }
But it did not work.

How can I additionally print all the entries of only one author (say Amy in the MWE, above)?

Thank you sooo much for helping.