# Biblatex: divide list of references in subparts by year (descending order)

Tags: biblatex

I would like to create a list of references ordered from the most recent to the oldest.

The MWE bellow gives a basic solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Rabelais1532,
  author = {Rabelais, Fran\c{c}ois},
  date = {1532},
  title = {Pantagruel},
  keywords = {1532},
}
@book{Hugo1862,
  author = {Hugo, Victor},
  date = {1862},
  title = {Les Mis\'{e}rables},
  keywords = {1862},
}
@book{Hugo1831,
  author = {Hugo, Victor},
  date = {1831},
  title = {Notre-Dame de Paris},
  keywords = {1831},
}
@book{Zola1885,
  author = {Zola, \'{E}mile},
  date = {1885},
  title = {Germinal},
  keywords = {1885},
}
@book{Balzac1831,
  author = {de Balzac, Honor\'{e}},
  date = {1831},
  title = {The Skin of Sorrow},
  keywords = {1831},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=References (default)]
\end{document}
```

However I would like to create some parts in the list, each part corresponding to a year, something like this:

```
\printbibliography[keyword=1885, title=1885]
\printbibliography[keyword=1862, title=1862]
\printbibliography[keyword=1831, title=1831]
\printbibliography[keyword=1532, title=1532]
```

I have tried to define filters in the preamble, modified from the `biblatex` documentation (§3.7.9, p. 89):

```
\defbibfilter{1885}{%
    date=1885
}%
```

and to add the following code:

```
\printbibliography[filter=1885, title=1885]
```

but the log file indicates:

`Package biblatex Error: Invalid filter expression.`

`Package biblatex Error: Filter '1885' not found.`

Is it possible, using filter commands for example, to automate the process with references ordered by year decreasing?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346564/35864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it would be nicer if the year lists would be generated automatically, so you don't have to write `\printbibliography[keyword=1885, title=1885]` etc.

The problem with your filter was that `date=1885` is not a valid filter expression. A filter can only have `(not)type`, `(not)subtype`, `(not)keyword` and `(not)field` (pure existence) expressions. For more complicated beasts you need a `bibcheck`. Indeed, this is what we use below. The `bibcheck` `thisyear` checks if an entry dates to a certain year.

Here I'm using LaTeX3 code to sort the list of all years easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g__blxbibbyyear_yearlist_seq

\cs_new:Npn \__blxbibbyyear_seq_gput_right_once:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnF #1 {#2}
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn #1 {#2} }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__blxbibbyyear_seq_gput_right_once:Nn { NV, Nx }


\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \blx_field_if_undef:n { p, T, F , TF }
  {
    \use:c { iffieldundef } { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
  }

% unfortunately, \iffieldint is not expandable, so no p version for us, boo
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \blx_field_if_int:n { T, F , TF }
  {
    \iffieldint { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
  }

\AtDataInput
  {
    \blx_field_if_undef:nF { labeldatesource }
      { 
        \blx_field_if_undef:nTF { \thefield{labeldatesource}year }
          {
            \blx_field_if_undef:nF { \thefield{labeldatesource} }
              {
                \blx_field_if_int:nT { \thefield{labeldatesource} }
                  {
                    \__blxbibbyyear_seq_gput_right_once:Nx \g__blxbibbyyear_yearlist_seq
                      { \thefield{\thefield{labeldatesource}} }
                  }
              }
          }
          {
            \__blxbibbyyear_seq_gput_right_once:Nx \g__blxbibbyyear_yearlist_seq
              { \thefield{\thefield{labeldatesource}year} }
          }
      }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \blxbibbyyear_seq_sort_bydirection:NN #1 #2
  {
    \seq_gsort:Nn #2
      {
         \int_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } #1 { ##2 }
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
          { \sort_return_same: }
      }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \blxbibbyyear_seq_sort_descending:N
  {
    \blxbibbyyear_seq_sort_bydirection:NN < #1
  }

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \blxbibbyyear_print_yearbib:nn #1 #2
  {
    \defbibcheck{thisyear}
      {
        \blx_field_if_int:nTF { labelyear }
          {
            \int_compare:nNnF { \thefield{labelyear} } = { #1 }
              { \skipentry }
          }
          { \skipentry }
      }
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title=#1, check=thisyear, #2]
  }


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\printbibbyyear}{O{}}
  {
    \blxbibbyyear_seq_sort_descending:N \g__blxbibbyyear_yearlist_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g__blxbibbyyear_yearlist_seq
      { \blxbibbyyear_print_yearbib:nn {##1} {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Rabelais1532,
  author = {Rabelais, Fran\c{c}ois},
  date = {1532},
  title = {Pantagruel},
}
@book{Hugo1862,
  author = {Hugo, Victor},
  date = {1862},
  title = {Les Mis\'{e}rables},
}
@book{Hugo1831,
  author = {Hugo, Victor},
  date = {1831},
  title = {Notre-Dame de Paris},
}
@book{Zola1885,
  author = {Zola, \'{E}mile},
  date = {1885},
  title = {Germinal},
}
@book{Balzac1831,
  author = {de Balzac, Honor\'{e}},
  year = {1831},
  title = {The Skin of Sorrow},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibbyyear
\end{document}
```

[image: Four bibliographies: One for each year]

Comment: moewe, a curiosity. Is there a reason why `biblatex` seems to refrain from LaTeX3 syntax? (If it does, but I don't recall ever seeing it in biblatex code).

Comment: I don't get a result compiling your code with the default option style=numeric of biblatex. I use pdfLaTeX, BibTeX (backend biber) and pdfLaTeX again. When I compile it first with style=authoryear and then switch to style=numeric it works at first. But after another compilation with BibTeX and pdfLaTeX no result is shown any more.

Comment: It should be used together with option labeldateparts=true. So \usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt, labeldateparts=true]{biblatex} works. This was a hint by gusbrs in another question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472588/sort-all-citations-from-one-year-automatically-under-a-heading-with-the-year-num)

Comment: @gusbrs Well, `biblatex` is not written in `expl3`, it uses normal LaTeX2e and `etoolbox` (also by Philip Lehman), so `expl3` language does not come naturally to the current code base. As to why LaTeX3 was not used for the code base, I don't know. LaTeX3 was around back in 2006 when `biblatex` development started (according to the changelog in `biblatex.tex`), but I'm not sure if it was considered stable enough to be the basis of such a large package. Plus there will have been the preferences of PL, not sure what his stance was towards `expl3` (given the state of the project back then).

Comment: ... It has been suggested once or twice that `biblatex` could benefit from `expl3`, but I'm not sure how good an idea it is to mix the current LaTeX2e base with `expl3` and re-implementing everything in `expl3` seems a huge task.

Comment: @Nico Indeed this code uses the `labelyear` for the headings. The `numeric` styles don't provide a labelyear by default and that could be enabled with `labeldateparts=true` (which is implicit here, because the MWE here uses `styke=authoryear` that sets the option internally).

Comment: @moewe It makes sense, I did expect some "path dependence" to be into play. Thanks.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the wonderful answer. When I was using your function to produce bibliography for different publication types (e.g. `\printbibbyyear[type=book]`), I was getting values of years for all publications regardless of type. Do you mind pointing me to the right direction to fix this? If you prefer me to open a different SE question, I will do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @XiaoyuLu At the moment I'm assuming that that would need nontrivial changes to the code, so I suggest a new question.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot. I have posted the question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476863/biblatex-showing-bibliography-group-by-type-while-sorting-by-year-descending.