# Is it possible to change the citation style in a chapter?

Tags: biblatex, citing, styles

I'm quite new to using BibLatex, so please forgive me if I my question is not well posed.
I'm working on a book, each chapter is in an independent file.

In the last chapter of the book I need to list several bibliographical references in chronological order. I used the \fullcite command to produce the citations.
My problem is that with the `authoryear` citation style I get, after the author's name, the year in parenthesis followed by a letter to distinguish the different article an author published in the same year and these letters are not in alphabetical order.

With this code

```
\documentclass[openany,italian]{book}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
citetracker=true,
citereset=chapter
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Prova.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{1899}
\end{center}

\noindent
\fullcite{anonimo_nuove_1899}, 1 giugno 1899.

\noindent
\fullcite{anonimo_limportante_1899-1}, 1 giugno 1899.

\noindent
\fullcite{anonimo_gli_1899}, 1-2 giugno 1899.

\noindent
\fullcite{anonimo_limportante_1899}, 2 giugno 1899.

\noindent
\fullcite{anonimo_liscrizione_1899}

\end{document}
```

I get this

[image]

This is my Prova.bib file, automatically generated with Zotero:

```
@article{anonimo_liscrizione_1899,
    title = {L’iscrizione arcaica del Foro Romano},
    volume = {11},
    pages = {211--214},
    journaltitle = {Bullettino dell'Istituto di diritto romano Vittorio Scialoja},
    author = {Anonimo},
    date = {1899},
    keywords = {Cippo},
}

@article{anonimo_limportante_1899,
    title = {L’importante scoperta al Foro},
    volume = {{XXXX}},
    number = {14241},
    journaltitle = {Perseveranza},
    author = {Anonimo},
    date = {1899},
    keywords = {Cippo},
}

@article{anonimo_limportante_1899-1,
    title = {L’importante scoperta al Foro Romano},
    volume = {{XVII}},
    number = {151},
    journaltitle = {Tribuna},
    author = {Anonimo},
    date = {1899},
    keywords = {Cippo},
}

@article{anonimo_nuove_1899,
    title = {Nuove scoperte nel Foro Romano},
    volume = {{XXVII}},
    number = {151},
    journaltitle = {Popolo Romano},
    author = {Anonimo},
    date = {1899},
    keywords = {Cippo},
}
@article{anonimo_gli_1899,
    title = {Gli scavi al Foro Romano},
    volume = {{XXIX}},
    number = {127},
    journaltitle = {Voce della Verità},
    author = {Anonimo},
    date = {1899},
    keywords = {Cippo},
}
```

Ideally, what I would like to obtain is this, which I manually wrote:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain this result without having to manually write all the bibliographical references. It would be great if it would be possible to change the citation style to `authortitle` only for this chapter, but I read that BibLatex doesn't support different citation styles in the same document.

Can you think of any possible workaround that could help me?

In the event I had to keep the year indication with the letter after the author's name, is there a way to change that letter so that they appear in alphabetical order?

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the long message.

Giulia

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Here's some guidance, how to convert code snippets into something we can work with here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my post with a MWE. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can remove the letters after the year with `labeldateparts=false`. In case you are trying to divide your bibliography by year, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434393/36296

Comment: If you only want to print the entries from one year, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346326/36296 on how to add a filter

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I actually have one big .bib file with all the entries I need for the book and use keywords to print a selected bibliography at the end of each chapter and I need the letters after the years in those chapters. So, my question now is, is it possible to remove the letters only for selected entries? Or, is there a way to decide which letter to assign to a specific entry so that they would appear in alphabetical order? Thank you!