# Date format (in bib entry) / bibelatex biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, date

I'm using biber and biblatex and I wanna print all thesis prior to 2013. When I use

```
year = {2010}
```

entry in the .bib file, every think works fine. However, if I use

```
date = {2010-11-25}
```

instead of year, my entry is ignored. I'm respecting the date format, right?
So what is wrong? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@THESIS{a,
  AUTHOR =  {Myself},
  TITLE = {Me, myself and I},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  year = {2010} 

} %  date = {2010-11-25}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
         \map[overwrite=true]{
            \step[fieldsource=year,  match=\regexp{199([7-9])|200([0-9])|201([0-2])},final]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={before2013}, append]
}}}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[type=thesis,keyword=before2013,title=Thesis,resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Biber's sourcemapping you can compare the `year` field with `biblatex` in the document. (We can use `year` here regardless of whether you used `year` or `date` since a `date` field is always split up into its components when it is written to the `.bbl`.)

We define a bibcheck

```
\defbibcheck{before2013}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2013}
       {}
       {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}
```

and use that check instead of the keyword

```
\printbibliography[type=thesis,check=before2013,title=Thesis,resetnumbers=true]
```

Comment: I just realised that I suggested something like this before in [biblatex, biber, is it possible to \printbibliography between two years?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346270/35864) - and so did Guido.

Comment: Right @moewe. Two solutions were proposed in that post and I took the other one (with the mapping)  which has the drawback (that I'm discovering right now) that the date splitting is done after mapping. So now I'm adopting your suggestion. Thx again for helping.

Answer (score 5):

Your `\maps` only sets `keyword=before2013` if `year` is 1997 up to 2012 but not if `date` is 1997-01-01 up to 2012-12-31. The index is only printed if `keyword=before2013`. So the entry would not be printed, if `date` instead of `year` is used.

You can add a similar map for `date` like you have for `year`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@THESIS{a,
  AUTHOR =  {Myself},
  TITLE = {Me, myself and I},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  year = {2010} 
}
@THESIS{b,
  AUTHOR =  {Another},
  TITLE = {Another, one and nobody},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  date = {2010-11-25} 
}
@THESIS{c,
  AUTHOR= {Never},
  TITLE = {I'm to late},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  date = {2017-01-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=year,  match=\regexp{199([7-9])|200([0-9])|201([0-2])},final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={before2013}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=date,  match=\regexp{199([7-9])|200([0-9])|201([0-2])},final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={before2013}, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[type=thesis,keyword=before2013,title=Thesis,resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution would be to use a check, because checks are done, when the date already has been splitted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@THESIS{a,
  AUTHOR =  {Myself},
  TITLE = {Me, myself and I},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  year = {2010} 
}
@THESIS{b,
  AUTHOR =  {Another},
  TITLE = {Another, one and nobody},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  date = {2010-11-25} 
}
@THESIS{c,
  AUTHOR= {Never},
  TITLE = {I'm to late},
  Institution = {My University},
  type = {Ph.D. thesis},
  date = {2017-01-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibcheck{before2013}{%
  \iffieldint{year}% If an interger field year exists
  {
    \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2013}% and the field value is less than 2013
    {}% do nothing
    {\skipentry}% otherwise skip the entry
  }
  {\skipentry}% skip the entrie also if there isn't an integer field year
}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[type=thesis,check=before2013,title=Thesis,resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much @Schweinebacke.
I thought however, when date is used, that the "Date Component Field"-year was correctly filled. All "Date Component Fileds" are described in p.150 of biblatex.pdf file: 
http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf 

Why is not it the case?

Comment: @rasha AFAIK automatic date splitting is done after mapping, before printing the entry and long after selecting the entries for the bibliography. If you think, this is a bug, make a bug report. I can only show you how to solve the problem with the current state of work.

Comment: @rasha Sourcemapping is one of the first steps when processing the bib file, before the `date` field is split into its components. This is desirable in most situations because then one can modify the raw input and does not have to worry about how Biber processes certain fields.

Comment: @rasha I've added an alternative using a check instead of source mapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Schweinebacke. I frankly prefer the latter solution, because I have hundreds of entries of different types to manage, with some of them having a "date" and some others "year" entries and not all the fields are rigorously entered (as usual :-)).